# Implicit cast operator in ActionResult<bool> not working

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1#actionresultt-type) to build my controllers. I do the following.

This is my controller:

```
// GET api/sth/{sthId}/isValid
[HttpGet("{sthId: int}/isValid")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[MyAuthorizeFilter]
public ActionResult<bool> Whatever(int sthId)
{
    return this.myService.Whatever(sthId);
}
```

Theoretically, this should be converted to an Ok() `ActionResult`. However, If I write the following unit test:

```
[Fact]
public void Whatever()
{
    this.myServiceMock.Setup(x => x.Whatever(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(true);

-> I DEBUG HERE ->  var result = this.myController.Whatever(1);

    Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
    Assert.True((bool)result.Value);
}
```

I see that my `result` is an `ActionResult<bool>` indeed, whose `Value` is `true` as expected, but `result.Result` is null. So: no `Ok` action result whatsoever.

What am I missing? Do I have to write explicitly the `return Ok()` to get it? With the sentence

> Implicit cast operators support the conversion of both `T` and `ActionResult` to `ActionResult<T>`. `T` converts to `ObjectResult`, which means `return new ObjectResult(T);` is simplified to `return T;`.

in the documentation I thought it was not necessary...?

Comment: What do you mean by _"but the Result is null"_? Of which type is that a property, and how do you inspect it?

Comment: `ActionResult<TValue>` class has two properties: `Result` and `Value`, and the `Result` one is null and I expect the Ok `ActionResult` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Update: I added the `<bool>` to clearly distinguish the `ActionResult<TValue>` and the `ActionResult`, which should be the `Result` of the `ActionResult<TValue>`

Comment: So in the last line of your test, it is the case that `result.Result == null`?

Comment: Exactly. I'll update the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ActionResult<TValue>` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

> wraps **either** an<sub>[sic]</sub> `TValue` instance or an `ActionResult`.

See also the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/f79f2e3b1200f8e672b77583a54e6157e49da9e4/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ActionResultOfT.cs), its constructors assign either `Value` or `Result`, never both.

The MVC pipeline will assign a success status code to the response if no status code was explicitly set. But I can't find documentation for that claim.

This means the response as obtained in this test won't have a status code or `OkActionResult` anywhere. You *can* convert it to an `ObjectResult`, but that won't have a status code.

Comment: I can't check `StatusCode` because the `result.Result` is null. If I return `Ok(this.myService.Whatever(sthId))` then in `result.Result` I have everything I need (`StatusCode == 200` and `Value == true`) and in `result.Value` I get `false`. With the sentence <<A 200 status code is returned with the corresponding `Product` object when the product does exist. Before ASP.NET Core 2.1, the `return product;` line had to be `return Ok(product);`.>> in the documentation I thought the action result was generated accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like swagger you will indeed get an OK from the server.

This happens to you because you dont perform an http request you simple call a method(your controller method) and you get a return type. You dont create a web server or something so no http status code is generated by .net core.

If you want to get status codes you should write test using http requests. Generally you could look up something like postman to perform your testing.

Comment: I thought the Ok for the swagger was generated by the `[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]` decorator...

Comment: @xavier No this annotation is simply info for your API. You don't need it. It just shows the user of the API what kind of results to expect. It's nothing more than info for the swagger at least to my knowledge

Comment: Ok, then I'll write the Ok( ) so that I can test it without having to use postman.